# IIF in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to convert an MS-Access query to a postgres statement so I can use it in SSRS. Seems to work great except for the IIF statement.

```
SELECT labor_sort_1.ncm_id
,IIf(labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid = 3721
 , ((labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 29 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops)
 , IIf(labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid = 3722
  , ((labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 24 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops)
  , IIf(labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid = 3755, ((labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 24 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops)
  , ((labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 17 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops)))) AS labor_cost
FROM ...
```

it returns the following message
 `function iif(boolean, interval, interval) does not exist`
How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this has been sitting around for a while but another option is to create a user defined function. If you happen to stumble upon this in your internet searches, this may be a solution for you.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION IIF(
        condition boolean, true_result TEXT, false_result TEXT
    ) RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
    BEGIN
     IF condition THEN
        RETURN true_result;
     ELSE
        RETURN false_result;
     END IF;
    END
    $$;

    SELECT IIF(2=1,'dan the man','false foobar');
```

Should text not tickle your fancy then try **function overloading**

Answer (score 21):

You'll need to switch the logic over to a [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) expression. CASE expression are standard for most RDBMS's so it's worth learning. In your case (pun intended) it would translate to:

```
CASE 
    WHEN labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid = 3721
        THEN (labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 29 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops
    WHEN labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid = 3722
        THEN (labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 24 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops
    WHEN labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid = 3755
        THEN (labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 24 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops
    ELSE
        (labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 17 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops)
    END AS labor_cost
```

Which is a lot cleaner looking since you don't have to monkey with nested `iif()` issues and all that and should you need to add more `employeeid`s to the list of hard-coded labor costs, it's no biggie.

You might also find it advantageous to us the `IN` condition instead so you only need two `WHEN` clauses:

```
CASE 
    WHEN labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid = 3721
        THEN (labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 29 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops
    WHEN labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid IN (3722, 3755)
        THEN (labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 24 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops
    ELSE
        (labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) * 24 * 17 * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops)
    END AS labor_cost
```

Also, you could move the CASE expression into the equation so the logic only needs to determine whatever number you wish to multiply by:

```
(labor_sort_1.MaxUpdatedAt - labor_sort_1.MinNCMScanTime) 
    * 24    
    * CASE  
        WHEN labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid = 3721 THEN 29
        WHEN labor_sort_1.sortby_employeeid IN (3722,3755) THEN 24
        ELSE 17
        END 
    * labor_sort_1.number_of_ops AS labor_cost
```

Comment: Awesome suggestion +1 and marked as the answer, however. Is there a way to create a function pg_temp function in postgres that would behave in the same way as a iif in ms access? (for my boss)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with postgres functions to say if that's possible. I assume it would be, but I would avoid doing it for two reasons 1) iif() is an oddball for RDBMSs. Every RDBMS under the sun uses CASE. To make your SQL more standard-ish switching to CASE would be a good idea. 2) I'm betting a UDF would be slower than something as deeply entrenched in RDBMS logic as a CASE.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I did some tweaking, and now it is in production.

Answer (score 16):

((this is a Wiki, you can edit!))

Same as @Daniel's answer, but **generalizing to any datatype**.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION iIF(
    condition boolean,       -- IF condition
    true_result anyelement,  -- THEN
    false_result anyelement  -- ELSE
) RETURNS anyelement AS $f$
  SELECT CASE WHEN condition THEN true_result ELSE false_result END
$f$  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

SELECT iif(0=1,1,2);
SELECT iif(0=0,'Hello'::text,'Bye');  -- need to say that string is text.
```

Good when you are looking for a [public-snippets-library](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Category:Snippets).

---

NOTE about `IMMUTABLE` and "PLpgSQL vs SQL".

- The `IMMUTABLE` clause is very important for code snippets like this, because, as said in the Guide: *"allows the optimizer to pre-evaluate the function when a query calls it with constant arguments"*
- PLpgSQL is the preferred language, except for "pure SQL". For [JIT optimizations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/jit-reason.html) (and sometimes for parallelism) SQL can obtain  better optimizations. Is something like copy/paste small piece of code instead of use a function call.

Important conclusion: this function, after optimizations, is so fast than the @JNevill's answer; it will compile to (exactly) the same internal representation. So, although it is not standard for PostgreSQL, it can be standard for your projects, by a centralized and reusable "library of snippets", like  [pg_pubLib](https://github.com/AddressForAll/pg_pubLib-v1).

Comment: I set mine back to being the answer because I tried your and it did not work. sorry .

Comment: This works, but for some data types, you need to specify the type of value being passed.
For example, 'w'::text. Otherwise, PostgreSQL cannot distinguish between 'w' is text or char.